# How to compare datetime strings inside a dict of a list with nested dicts?

Tags: python, list, datetime, dictionary

I'm writing a function that takes a vendorID and a date_time string that should return if a vendorID can deliver if time/date doesn't overlap for a delivery to be done.

I'm trying to compare datetime strings inside a dict that has a list of nested dict with various elements including the datetime string. I want to compare each datetime string from each nested dict inside the list and check if the date is different and then compare if a certain amount of minutes have been passed.

Tried to loop through dict and items and use datetime.strptime() to parse the datetime string but I'm not sure how to compare the dates inside the list of dicts when iterating through the dict items.

```
   dict = {
"results": [
{
    "vendor_id": 1,                    
    "client_id": 10,                   
    "datetime": "2017-01-01 13:30:00"  
},
{
    "vendor_id": 1,
    "client_id": 40,
    "datetime": "2017-01-01 14:30:00"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change time of `string` type to `datetime` type.
And, Just you use `-`.
After that, You can use `timedelta` what is returned by `time_diff` function if you handle the time more.
If you want to get minutes, use `seconds` attribute.

```
from datetime import datetime

def time_diff (a, b):
    return a - b

dict = {
"results": [
{
    "vendor_id": 1,                    
    "client_id": 10,                   
    "datetime": "2017-01-01 13:30:00"  
},
{
    "vendor_id": 1,
    "client_id": 40,
    "datetime": "2017-01-01 14:30:00"
}
]
}


for r in dict['results']:
    r['datetime'] = datetime.strptime(r['datetime'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print (int(time_diff(dict['results'][1]['datetime'], dict['results'][0]['datetime']).seconds/60))
```

Comment: Great, as I wasn't indexing results correctly. How can I get the time_diff to be specifically in minutes?

Comment: @JonMontgomery   Updated

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.
 Using dict as you have advised;

```
dict = {
    "results": [
    {
        "vendor_id": 1,
        "client_id": 10,
        "datetime": "2017-01-01 13:30:00"
    },
    {
        "vendor_id": 1,
        "client_id": 40,
        "datetime": "2017-01-01 14:30:00"
    }]}
```

Having some date times, use the for loop and test if;

```
somedatetime1 = '2017-01-01 14:00:00'
somedatetime2 = '2017-01-01 15:00:00'

for d in dict['results']:
    if d['datetime'] < somedatetime1:
        print('somedatetime1 :: Vendor {} Client {} DateTime {}'.format(d['vendor_id'], d['client_id'], d['datetime']))
    if d['datetime'] < somedatetime2:
        print('somedatetime2 :: Vendor {} Client {} DateTime {}'.format(d['vendor_id'], d['client_id'], d['datetime']))
```

Returns;
somedatetime1 :: Vendor 1 Client 10 DateTime 2017-01-01 13:30:00
somedatetime2 :: Vendor 1 Client 10 DateTime 2017-01-01 13:30:00
somedatetime2 :: Vendor 1 Client 40 DateTime 2017-01-01 14:30:00

Answer (score 0):

I would think it would be easier to do this in pandas as you can groupby vendor ID and do operations only for that vendor.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame() #Initiate
grp = df.from_dict(dict['results']).groupby('vendor_id') #Convert into df and groupby vendor id, should be useful when u have more than one vendor
dct = {}

for group in grp.groups:
    df_vid = grp.get_group(group) # Obtain data for that vendor
    df_vid['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_vid['datetime'])
    ab = np.array(df_vid['datetime'])
    dist = euclidean_distances(ab.reshape(-1, 1), ab.reshape(-1, 1)) # Find distance matrix
    dct[group] = dist # Assign it to dict by vendor ID as key
```